# Drudging through email logs

Tags: software-rec, logs, email, qmail

I am in charge of maintaining a linux e-mail server running `qmail` on Red Hat Linux.

Fairly often, I have to trace the path of some email through syslog and to be frank, this is rather tedious.

Are there any desktop apps (or even command tools) that inspect the incoming and outgoing mail logs with better usability instead of clobbering bash commands together?

What I have in mind is some tool that I could import a log file and it would organize all the information for me, so that I could perform some searches on it, or view the path of email messages in and out of my system.

Perhaps this is lofty wishes at the moment, but I'm trying to see what my options are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com). You can download  a version for free -- at least to dig into a couple log files for you. It will help you manage your log files and also know whats going on in your system. It's quick to setup.

Comment: great suggestion! Exactly the type of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'd never heard of Splunk but when I saw [DLZ's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15902/drudging-through-email-logs/15928#15928) I [looked up alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/splunk/?platform=linux). It looks like there are a couple open source alternatives. [Logstash](http://logstash.net/) looks particularly interesting although [Graylog2](http://www.graylog2.org/) seems to have some ninja tricks up it's sleeve too.

Comment: @WOW! Good job Caleb! Graylog2 looks real interesting. Looks like I have a few toys to tinker with for a while. Thanks Much!!